# Custom Code Errors in FLutter FLow. i am getting this error when i try to compile my custom code

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, flutterflow

i have checked that all my names of widgets and actions are same to there file name .. i have also checked that all variable are declared by there type (Not dynamically variables created).
but still getting same  issue .. i even dont know which file has this issue .
i have tried to run it in local machine by downloading code and it works fine no error .
any help in this regard will be appreciated
thanks in advance

i have checked that all my names of widgets and actions are same to there file name .. i have also checked that all variable are declared by there type (Not dynamically variables created).
but still getting same  issue .. i even dont know which file has this issue .
i have tried to run it in local machine by downloading code and it works fine no error .
any help in this regard will be appreciated

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.